# Is there a term for when one word is used as a generic blanket term, even though it may be technically inaccurate?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Periodically I'll hear people refer to their six-cylinder engine as a *V6*, when it's actually an inline-six or a horizontally opposed engine.  And I've actually done this myself--unintentionally called an engine a *V6* that I knew as actually an inline-six.

I'm reminded of *generic trademarks*, but in this scenario there is no trademark.

I can't think of any other examples at the moment, but I would describe the phenomena I notice as using one term that means a very specific scenario, to be a blanket to refer to all related scenarios.

Comment: Isn't 'blanket term' itself broad enough encompass any and all situations where a generalized word is used? Considering how often it happens in daily speech, whether to indulge a layman or just because someone can't be bothered to go into more detail...

Comment: Is the _technical inaccuracy_ significant in the context of use? If you're racing with, or working on the engine, it is. If you're comparing cars on coarse grounds of power, efficiency or "sportiness", it isn't...

Comment: This often happens when people mean to say, "It's got a _six_" and it comes out _V6_...

Comment: @Useless, I would say the *technically inaccuracy* is significant.  I don't use that phrase to mean true computer-driven technical calculations.  Rather, to highlight that while the theme or key significance of the statement is true (that the car has six cylinders, perhaps instead of four), a small but significant detail is incorrectly stated.

Comment: The technical inaccuracy is significant in a technical discussion (so the speaker is making an actual error), but insignificant if you're just comparing _vroom-vroom_ noises outside a bar with your friends. They're different contexts, with different requirements for accuracy and styles of speech, and I'm still not sure which one you're asking about.

Comment: I don't mean this in a technical discussion as you describe (i.e., I'm not talking about one engineer speaking to another over diagnostics).  Given your scenarios, my question is directed at the latter scenario.  You're right, that the difference in engine configuration between two six-cylinders is insignificant compared to the difference between a four- and a six-cylinder.  But to automotive enthusiasts (at least my close group), we would take note of being told an engine is a V6 if one of us thought it to be an inline-6.

Answer (score 3):

**Misnomer**: a wrong name or inappropriate designation

[From MW Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misnomer)

Your example is similar to calling a tissue a "Kleenex" where one is describing a generic noun using a popular brand name. Apparently that's also called a **Proprietary Eponym**.
[Source](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/eponyms.shtml)

Comment: Other examples would be 'tin can', 'tin foil', 'digital darkroom', etc.

Comment: The Kleenex example is _also_ synechdoche, so we're back to whether it's used in error or as a rhetorical device. Unless the context requires a very accurate discrimination between the properties of different brands of tissue, I think it's unlikely to be the former. For the original question, it depends on whether the technical inaccuracy is a problem or not.

Comment: @Terah _tin can_ is not a misnomer for a can made of tin. It isn't a misnomer for a can plated in tin. It isn't obviously inappropriate for a can-which-would-formerly-have-been-plated-in-tin-but-now-uses-plastic, except in the context of a detailed discussion on food storage technology, where the exact coating matters more than the general function.

Comment: @Useless - Fair point! I (not so obviously I guess) meant that in relation to modern cans made of aluminium. I should have been more specific there. (Which I'll be now concerning the 'tin foil', which would be a misnomer when used to refer to aluminium foil :))

Answer (score 0):

It's the *specific for general* case from the definition of [Synecdoche](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synecdoche) below:

> A figure of speech in which the name of a part is used to stand for
>   the whole (as hand for sailor), the whole for a part (as the law for
>   police officer), **the specific for the general (as cutthroat for
>   assassin)**, the general for the specific (as thief for pickpocket), or
>   the material for the thing made from it (as steel for sword).

ie, you're using a well-known example of the category as a blanket term for the category as a whole.

Comment: Synechdoche doesn't really account for the mistake to which the OP is referring, though I thought of that as well.

Comment: A misnomer is using the wrong name for something, presumably by mistake. Synechdoche is _deliberately_ used. Although OP says the substitution is _technically inaccurate_, I'm not at all clear that it is an error of language.

Comment: I can see your point. I do think that there is a difference. It's just a comment, not an argument. I think maybe the OP is referring to something nuanced, more nuanced than, say, calling a dust mot a broom.

Comment: I see that definition of synecdoche all over the internet, so I won't argue; however, I would like to recommend literarydevices.net, which makes a case for a more narrow definition. Compare with metonymy. https://literarydevices.net/synecdoche/ and https://literarydevices.net/metonymy/

Comment: @tbc0 - post it as an answer! Since I don't like the _misnomer_ answer, but can only down-vote it once, I'll definitely upvote a more accurate answer than mine.

Comment: @useless I upvoted misnomer. I abstained on your answer. After recommending literarydevices.net I dug through that site looking for some authority. I found none. This is going to take more research. Why don't you edit your answer to talk about metonymy? Maybe then I'll upvote it.